# How to properly align each word in an html header?

Tags: html, css

So for school I need to finish this assignment for developing a website and **what I need is for it to look like this:**

[image]

**But instead I have this**

[image]

The words in my headers "THIS MUST BE THE PLACE (NAIVE MELODY)" and so on need to be properly aligned, but instead it looks like a list.
     I've tried many different methods or lines of code to fix it, but it just doesn't seem to work. Here's my html file.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 900px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h6 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
}

pre {
  display: block;
  font-style: oblique;
  white-space: pre;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

#picture {
  float: center;
  /*Make sure width and height are properly adjusted*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  /* The image keeps its original aspect ratio and the image area is completely covered. Show only a 
    poriton of the picture*/
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.767);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  /*background-size: 50%;*/
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /*width: 80%;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  /* Adjust width and left of container content accordingly*/
  left: 12%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 1000px;
}

.container .content .h5a h5 {
  margin: 5%;
  text-align: right;
  word-spacing: normal;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>The Lyrics Party></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Exercise 3b.css">


  <body>
    <html>

    <style>
      h2 {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 149);
        font-style: oblique;
      }
      
      h3 {
        color: grey;
        font-style: bold;
      }
      
      h4 {
        color: grey
      }
      
      h5 {
        color: yellow;
      }
      
      h6 {
        color: white;
      }
      
      p {
        color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.918);
      }
    </style>


    <!--Align first head to the center-->

    <div>The Lyrics Party </div>
    <h6>home top songs community</h6>




    <!--<div class="crop">-->
    <!--Create div for "divimg" border-->
    <div class="container">
      <!--Use for image-->
      <!--stlye: Adjust size and location-->
      <!--Adjust img size to fit in border-->
      <img id="picture" src="talking_heads-speaking_in_tongues.img.png" );>

      <div class="content">

        <head>
          <div class="h5a">
            <!--Use pre for proper sentence structure-->
            <!--<div class="adjust">-->
            <h5>THIS MUST BE THE PLACE (NAIVE MELODY)
            </h5>

            <!--<div class="t.h.adjust">
            <h4><font size="9", color="yellow"><b> MELODY)</font></b></h4></div>-->

            <!--<div class="T adjust">-->
            <h6>TALKINGHEADS</h6>
            <h6>
              <font size="4">ALBUM:SPEAKINGINTONGUES</font>
            </h6>
          </div>


        </head>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--</div>-->



    <!--Use to change font size.-->


    <!--Move lyrics  to the right side of the page-->
    <h4>
      <font size="5">[Verse 1]</font>
    </h4>
    <pre>
    Home is where I want to be 
    Pick me up and turn me round 
    I feel numb, born with a weak heart 
    I guess I must be having fun 
    The less we say about it, the better 
    Make it up as we go along 
    Feet on the ground, head in the sky            
    </pre>

    <h4>
      <font size="5">[Chorus]</font>
    </h4>

    <pre>
    Hi-yeah, I got plenty of time 
    Hi-yeah, you got light in your eyes 
    And you're standing here beside me 
    I love the passing of time 
    Never for money, always for love 
    Cover up and say goodnight, say goodnight       
    </pre>

    <h4>
      <font size="5">[Verse 2]</font>
    </h4>

    <pre>
    Home is where I want to be 
    But I guess I'm already there 
    I come home, she lifted up her wings 
    I guess that this must be the place 
    I can't tell one from the other 
    Did I find you or you find me? 
    There was a time before we were born 
    If someone asks, this is where I'll be, where I'll be
    </pre>


</head>



<video width="400" controls>
                <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RjHflb-QgVc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjHflb-QgVc/" target="_blank">HTML Tutorial for Beginners</a>



<!--Upload link address-->

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: your HTML semantics itself needs correction. `eg` head tag does not go inside the body tag

Answer (score 0):

The correct structure for HTML doc is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  All your body and headings should be here. 
  You have html tag inside body then you have body inside head.
  Imagine the document being a man. Would it be having a head inside it's body?
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the head in twice in your HTML. However to fix the title that you asked about try removing these below within your CSS...

```
.container .content {
/*remove this or set to 100%*/
width: 65%;
/*remove this*/
padding-right: 1000px;
}

.container .content .h5a h5 {
/*remove this*/
padding-right: 1000px;
}
```